# Sharepoint Online 2013 calendar view of blog posts list doesn't always show all items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, calendar

In several blog sites I created a calendar view of the posts list filtering on the category field. I copied the exact configuration to another site and the items in the list initially showed but then disappeared without me knowingly changing anything.

The items now don't show in the default calendar.aspx page so I've ruled out some conflict with other page elements. I also removed the filter so that's not a factor either. it seems like the calendar view gets corrupted, but how do I debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Odd, but I created a new calendar view the exact same way and the "missing" items rendered. Switched the web part on a page over to the new view and all is well, Can only assume the first view got corrupted somehow which isn't unusual in SP.